# Openshift Jobs - apply configuration

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

For Openshift jobs, one way is to use the oc run command to execute a command against an image, this will run the command inside a pod. Is there way to apply configuration such as a config map or secret to this mechanism (oc run).

Please advise.
B

Comment: i can create pod object, and associate env based on secret or config map.

Comment: If you use ``oc run ...youoptions... --dry-run -o json`` it will output the raw JSON description. You could use that as a starting point and add to it the bits necessary to extract environment variables from a config map or secret, or mount the config map or secret.

Comment: thanks, but i can add the env. vars referring to configmap/secret to oc run?

Comment: Can you include in your question the current ``oc run`` command you are using. If you do that then can generate the output and use it as an example of how you can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a deployment config for these requirement. In which you can declare environment variables, commands, declare secrets etc. It will be easy to maintain too.

Comment: I need the pod to have a restartpolicy of Never. DC only supports Always.

Comment: you can use pod in kind like in below example, which will run the pod only and will not restart once pod deleted. in this also you can declare env and command options in container section. See this example not complete but you will get the idea.apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod

Answer (score 0):

see this example pod in kind. in this you can also add command and env variables. it will not restart the container itself. not complete but you will get the idea.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-elasticsearch-1
  namespace: common-data
  labels:
    elasticsearch-name: pod-elasticsearch-1
    node: elasticsearch
    type: elasticsearch-logs
spec:
  containers:
    - resources:
        limits:
          memory: "24Gi"
          cpu: "2"
        requests:
          memory: "16Gi"
          cpu: "1"
      ulimits:
        memlock:
          soft: -1
          hard: -1
        nofile:
          soft: 65536
          hard: 65536
      image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.2
      name: elasticsearch-custom
      command: [ "elasticsearch"]
      args: ["-E" , "cluster.name=es-ocp-app-cluster",
                "-E" , "node.name=master-es-node-1",
                "-E" , "node.master=true",
                "-E" , "node.data=true",
                "-E" , "network.publish_host= svc-elasticsearch-1 ",
                #"-E" , "network.host=_site_",
                "-E" , "http.host=0.0.0.0",
```